# Unable to update to Evolution version 3.10.1?

Tags: installation, compiling, evolution

I'm unable to update to the lastest stable version of evolution. I got the `.tar.xz` file but I cannot install it.

Appreciate your assistance

Comment: did you extract `.tar.xz` file?.what error did you face while installing?

Answer (score 1):

This PPA https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/gnome3-staging has Evolution 3.10.1-2ubuntu3~saucy1 (note that the slightly more stable gnome3 ppa actually would move you backwards to Evolution 3.8.2-0ubuntu1~raring1).

This PPA requires both the main GNOME3 PPA and gnome3-next PPA (Saucy only).

This staging ppa comes with the warning "The packages here have been deemed not ready for general use, they have known bugs and/or regressions, sometimes of a critical nature. Mostly things should run smoothly but be prepared to use ppa-purge, when you encounter issues!"

I found that while this did get me to Evolution 3.10.1, it caused significant bugginess in Unity and in general (settings fails to work, the mouse is invisible, etc. etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Could you please give more information to understand the issue? How are you trying to install and whats happening? Which Ubuntu version? Also last stable  Evolution is 3.10.2

However in order to build Evolution you need Gnome 2.6 development libraries installed,  that's usually included in newer distributions.

As per Evolution wiki you need these dependencies, besides the stock GNOME libraries

```
* gnome-icon-theme 1.2.0 or later

* ORBit 2.9.8 or later

     ftp://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/sources/libsoup

* libsoup 2.2.1 or later

     ftp://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/sources/libsoup

* evolution-data-server 1.1.1 or later

     ftp://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/sources/evolution-data-server

* gtkhtml 3.5.0 or later

     ftp://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/sources/gtkhtml
```

If all dependencies meet Evolution have install-sh script included in tarball which you need to make executable and run it.

Probably easier  solution is to use an PPA for installation but most likely the Evolution version could be older.

By default these bellow are included versions  of evolution in official Ubuntu repos (tested to work properly).
The Trusty Tahr (active development) ~
  3.8.5-2ubuntu1     release (main)

The Saucy Salamander (current stable release) ~
  3.8.4-0ubuntu1     release (main)

The Raring Ringtail (supported) ~
  3.6.4-0ubuntu1     release (main)

The Quantal Quetzal (supported) ~
  3.6.0-0ubuntu3     release (main) & 
  3.6.2-0ubuntu0.1   updates (main)

The Precise Pangolin (supported) ~
  3.2.3-0ubuntu6     release (main)